# Thread id on different linux distros

Tags: linux, rhel, thread

We have a server application which runs fine on ubuntu and the old Mandrake linux, but it consistently fails on Redhat Enterprise Linux (to be precise RHEL 4 Update 8, kernel 2.6.9-89). On RHEL the server usually runs for 40 or more days and after that it stops responding to the incoming connections.

We've noticed that on ubuntu for about 5000 incoming connections the server creates only about 50 unique thread ids. At the same time on RHEL for the same amount of incoming connections there are thousands of thread ids. I think that this might be a reason behinds these server hangs.

Is there any way that i can check if this is the reason? Maybe some tool which can show the number of "free" threads in the system or a tool which can show "thread leak" in the server? Is there a system setting that controls how threads are allocated and freed? Maybe there's some setting which "bind" a particular thread to an incoming TCP connection and this works differently in ubuntu and RHEL?

**PS**

I forgot to mention that on RHEL a thread id usually looks like this xxxx004 or xxxx005, where x is some hex digit, e.g. 1E8004 and 750005, and they are always increasing over time.

Comment: Do you have the source code?

Answer (score 1):

#### /proc

This sounds like you're butting into the thread-max limit. You can check this parameter here:

```
$ cat /proc/sys/kernel/threads-max
12345
```

You can change this value with this command:

```
$ sudo echo <number> > /proc/sys/kernel/threads-max
```

To make it permanent for reboots, edit this file, `/etc/sysctl.conf`, and add this line:

```
kernel.threads-max = 50000
```

Then run this command:

```
$ sudo sysctl -p
```

#### Additional Kernel Parameters

You can check out other configurables for the Kernel using the command `sysctl -a`.

For example, here's all the "thread" parameters:

```
$ sudo sysctl -a|grep thread
kernel.threads-max = 7514
kernel.slow-work.min-threads = 2
kernel.slow-work.max-threads = 16
vm.nr_pdflush_threads = 0
```

#### 2.6 vs. 3.x Kernels

Drawing a comparison between the RHEL 4.x which is using a dated 2.6 Kernel and glibc library vs. the newer 3.x is is like comparing apples to oranges. There have been numerous changes to the kernel so I wouldn't expect either of them to behave in a similar fashion.